# Upper and lower sums - Riemann Integrals

Tags: real-analysis, riemann-sum, riemann-integration

I'm not particularly strong in these types of questions and I never know where to begin.

> Let $g(x) = 1/x$ for $1 ≤ x ≤ 3$ and let $\pi$ be the partition$  \{1, 2, 3 \} $ of
>   $[1, 3]$. Find $m(π)$ and $M(π)$, the lower and upper sums for $g$ using $\pi$, respectively.

From what I know,

$m(π) = {\sum_1^n} (x_i-x_{i-1})\inf(g(x)|[x_{i-1},x_i])$

$M(π) = {\sum_1^n} (x_i-x_{i-1})\sup[g(x)|[x_{i-1},x_i])$

How do I go about working with these partitions to solve this?

Comment: $1/x$ is decreasing on $[1,3]$.  Does that help?

Comment: Not particularly. I have a very limited background in these types of question and I'm not sure how that applies.

Comment: First draw a picture.  Then figure how many rectangles you're supposed to find the area of given your particular partition.  Then figure out the width of each rectangle.  Then figure out the height of each rectangle.  Then calculate.

Comment: Oh, are you suggesting that the inf of the domain is always the right end point and sup is always the left end point? If that's it, do I just have to evaluate the sum? That seems too easy.

Comment: Yes.  You'll use the rightmost points for $m(\pi)$ and the leftmost point in each interval for $M(\pi)$.  This isn't supposed to be a very difficult problem.

Comment: [Here's](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=riemann+sum&a=*C.riemann+sum-_*Calculator.dflt-&f2=1%2Fx&f=IntegralMethodCalculator.integrand%5Cu005f1%2Fx&f3=x&f=IntegralMethodCalculator.variable%5Cu005fx&f4=1&f=IntegralMethodCalculator.rangestart%5Cu005f1&f5=3&f=IntegralMethodCalculator.rangeend%5Cu005f3&f6=1&f=IntegralMethodCalculator.intervalsize_1) what your upper sum should look like.

Comment: @user282934 For a decreasing function, the upper sum is the left hand sum and the lower sum is the right hand sum. Similarly, for an increasing function, the upper sum is the right hand sum and the lower sum is the left hand sum. For a general function you're stuck with the formulas you wrote in the OP.